# Get column value by name rather than position in cx_Oracle

Tags: python, cx-oracle

Using `cx_Oracle`, I am selecting data from an Oracle database.

```
curs = cxn.cursor()
result = curs.execute(SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Person)
```

Is there a way to return only the firstname without numerical index?  For example:

```
for row in result:
    result[0] #will return the first column
```

What I am hoping to do is call the value like `result['FirstName']`

Comment: No. The API returns a python `list` when SELECT statements are used, not a `dict` which is needed to support keyword indexing like 'FirstName'

Comment: Note that `cursor.execute` return value is unspecified in the API spec (but [is specified to be the cursor itself](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html#Cursor.execute) in `cx_Oracle` docs).

Answer (score 7):

You can use a row factory to return a row that responds to names in addition to indices. One simple way to do that is using collections.namedtuple, as in the following code (which uses the cx_Oracle test suite setup):

```
import cx_Oracle
import collections

connection = cx_Oracle.Connection("cx_Oracle/dev@localhost/orcl")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from TestStrings")
names = [c[0] for c in cursor.description]
cursor.rowfactory = collections.namedtuple("TestStrings", names)
for row in cursor:
    print(row)
    print(row[0])
    print(row.STRINGCOL)
```

You can also look at the sample provided in the cx_Oracle repository, as well, for further inspiration.

https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/main/samples/rows_as_instance.py

You can use an output type handler as well to make this all seamless, too. I will add that sample to the cx_Oracle repository later on.

Comment: Sample code was moved to:
https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/main/samples/rows_as_instance.py

Answer (score 1):

DB API 2.0 does not provide such a capability. Anything various DB client modules provide like this is nonstandard.

The API does, however, provide the [`cursor.description`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#description) read-only attribute with this information:

> This read-only attribute is a sequence of 7-item sequences.
>
> Each of these sequences contains information describing one result
>   column:
>
> - name
> - type_code
> - display_size
> - internal_size
> - precision
> - scale
> - null_ok
>
> The first two items ( name and type_code ) are mandatory, the other
>   five are optional and are set to None if no meaningful values can be
>   provided.
>
> <...>

So, you can do like this:

```
for row in result:
    result[(i for i,cd in enumerate(result.description) if cd[0]=='column_name').next()]
```

Rather wordy and should be only called once, so it's reasonable to move this to a subroutine:

```
def columns(cursor):
    return {cd[0]:i for i,cd in enumerate(cursor.description)}
<...>
result=c.execute(...)
ccls=columns(result)
for row in result:
    row[ccls['name']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
nmcol=[row[0] for row in c.description]
# print(nmcol)
for row in cursor:
  print(row[nmcol.index('FirstName')])
```