# Selecting Column and data from Oracle in Python scipt

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I would like to read row by row in python from Oracle Select query. I have to build a logic based on the data I am getting from Oracle for specific columns.

I am using cx_Oracle.connect

```
dsnStr = cx_Oracle.makedsn("xxxx.net", "6000", "XVTRR") # Dev envrionment
con = cx_Oracle.connect(user="SCOTT", password="TIGER", dsn=dsnStr)
print con.version
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from user_tables where rownum<=1 order by TABLE_NAME")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
col_names=[]

for i in range(0, len(cursor.description)):
    col_names.append(cursor.description[i][0])
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(width=1024)
pp.pprint(col_names)
pp.pprint(rows)
cursor.close()
con.close()
```

Please help me.

Comment: Hello, any one can help, please ?

Comment: Found the answer though ! Thanks ! 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565189/get-column-value-by-name-rather-than-position-in-cx-oracle